# addit function with variables

Tags: python, function

I want to know what the following code means and what each of `a`, `b`, and `c` become:

```
def addit(a,b,*c):
     return a+b+sum(c)

    addit(3,5,15,21,5)
```

Comment: This is silly way to reproduce the `sum` function.

Comment: put a `print` statement before the return statement and you'll probably be able to answer it yourself: `print a, b, c`..(hint: should give you `3 5 (15, 21, 5))`

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` are the first two arguments (`3` and `5`, respectively, in your example). `c` is a positional argument - it's a list of all the arguments from the third onward (in your example, it is `(15, 21, 5)`).